# dropdown select in rails with bootstrap select view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have below select option in rails project:

```
 <select name="reporter[website_ip]">
    <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@websites,:website_ip, :website_address) %>
 </select>
```

and below select bootstrap html code:

```
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Medium Dropdown</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select class="medium m-wrap" tabindex="1">
          <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
          <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
          ...
          <option value="Category n">Category n</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want use rails select option with this select bootstrap template. How can I do this? I use below code, but not working.

```
<div class="control-group">
  <select name="reporter[website_ip]">
    <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@websites,:website_ip, :website_address) %>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive that you can do it this way:

```
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Medium Dropdown</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="reporter[website_ip]" class="medium m-wrap" tabindex="1">
           <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@websites,:website_ip, :website_address) %>
        </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you replace "options_from_collection_for_select" with "collection_select"? Then I use this code, I get "NoMethodError","undefined method 'reporter[website_ip]'".

Comment: I've updated the answer usign the "options_from_collection_for_select", hope this snippet of code can help you.